# Combining Excel Formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm trying to do something on Excel which isn't working. I've managed 2 separate formulas that work separately but can't figure out how to combine them.
Separate formulas are:

```
=IF(K3>I3,"","Yes")
```

and

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(D3,{"Opportunity Qualified","KDM Needs Defined","Proposition Developed","Terms & Stock OK","VP Pitched to KDM","Reshaped & Repitched","Won Pending Invoice"})\*{1,2,3,4,5,6,7})
```

I want to replace the values `K3` and `I3` with the `=(SUM(COUNTIF....` value but am getting an error message when I do this:

```
=IF((SUM(COUNTIF(K4,{"Opportunity Qualified","KDM Needs Defined","Proposition Developed","Terms & Stock OK","VP Pitched to KDM","Reshaped & Repitched","Won Pending Invoice"})\*{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}))>(SUM(COUNTIF(I4,{"Opportunity Qualified","KDM Needs Defined","Proposition Developed","Terms & Stock OK","VP Pitched to KDM","Reshaped & Repitched","Won Pending Invoice"})\*{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}),"","Yes"))
```

Any ideas? I'm a bit of an Excel novice but this formula looks overly complicated!

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the `SUM(COUNTIF` formula with `MATCH`, e.g.

`=MATCH(D3,{"Opportunity Qualified","KDM Needs Defined","Proposition Developed","Terms & Stock OK","VP Pitched to KDM","Reshaped & Repitched","Won Pending Invoice"},0)`

You can then use that version with your IF formula - If you use a Name to name that list as **List** then your formula can be this:

`=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(K4,List,0),0)>IFERROR(MATCH(K4,List,0),0),"","Yes")`